# Extracting fixed vectors from BioBERT without using terminal command?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, pytorch

If we want to use weights from pretrained [BioBERT](https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert) model, we can execute following terminal command after downloading all the required BioBERT files.

```
os.system('python3 extract_features.py \
      --input_file=trial.txt \
      --vocab_file=vocab.txt \
      --bert_config_file=bert_config.json \
      --init_checkpoint=biobert_model.ckpt \
      --output_file=output.json')
```

The above command actually reads individual file containing the text, reads the textual content from it, and then writes the extracted vectors to another file. So, the problem with this is that it could not be scaled easily for very large data-sets containing thousands of sentences/paragraphs.

Is there is a way to extract these features on the go (using an embedding layer) like it could be done for the word2vec vectors in PyTorch or TF1.3?

Note: BioBERT checkpoints do not exist for TF2.0, so I guess there is no way it could be done with TF2.0 unless someone generates TF2.0 compatible checkpoint files.

I will be grateful for any hint or help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the contextual embeddings on the fly, but the total time spend on getting the embeddings will always be the same. There are two options how to do it: 1. import BioBERT into the Transformers package and treat use it in PyTorch (which I would do) or 2. use the original codebase.

**1. Import BioBERT into the Transformers package**

The most convenient way of using pre-trained BERT models is the [Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) package. It was primarily written for PyTorch, but works also with TensorFlow. It does not have BioBERT out of the box, so you need to convert it from TensorFlow format yourself. There is `convert_tf_checkpoint_to_pytorch.py` script that does that. People had some issues with this script and BioBERT ([seems to be resolved](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/457)).

After you convert the model, you can load it like this.

```py
import torch
from transformers import *

# Load dataset, tokenizer, model from pretrained model/vocabulary
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('directory_with_converted_model')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('directory_with_converted_model')

# Call the model in a standard PyTorch way
embeddings = model([tokenizer.encode("Cool biomedical tetra-hydro-sentence.", add_special_tokens=True)])
```

**2. Use directly BioBERT codebase**

You can get the embeddings on the go basically using the code that is [`exctract_feautres.py`](https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert/blob/master/extract_features.py). On lines 346-382, they initialize the model. You get the embeddings by calling `estimator.predict(...)`.

For that, you need to format your format the input. First, you need to format the string (using code on line 326-337) and then apply and call [`convert_examples_to_features`](https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert/blob/5aefd07bbffaea2ee425425121b4119f34880163/extract_features.py#L210) on it.

Comment: Thank you the answer @Jindrich. With the first approach, I get following error, "TypeError: ones_like() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (Tensor input, bool requires_grad)"

Comment: I get this error at following line "embeddings = model([tokenizer.tokenize("Cool biomedical tetra-hydro-sentence.")])
"

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be `encode`, not `tokenize`, so you get tensor of vocabulary indices, not a list of tokens.

Comment: I tried it with encode a day before, but it still gives out error:  AttributeError: 'BertTokenizer' object has no attribute 'encoder'

Comment: Iťs just `encode`, not encoder. Sorry for the typo. Have a look at README of the github page of the package, they have pretty nice examples there (and without typos).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry!! It was a typo by me. It works as you said using the method 1 now. However, I had to replace "model = BertModel.from_pretrained('directory_with_converted_model')" to model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased') to make the tokenizer work.